# Window's DIB (Device independent bitmap) show's other window?

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap

I am learning how to make a game from scatch in c++ with the HandMadeHero series. Problem is, when I use a Bitmap inside of my window, it displays other windows for some reason.

Image explains it a lot better:

[image]

Here is the current code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define local_function static
#define local_persist static
#define global_variable static

global_variable bool running = true;
global_variable BITMAPINFO BitmapInfo;
global_variable void *BitmapMemory;
global_variable HBITMAP BitmapHandle;
global_variable HDC BitmapDeviceContext;

local_function void ResizeDIBSection(int width, int height) {

    if (BitmapHandle) {
        DeleteObject(BitmapHandle);
    }

    if (!BitmapDeviceContext) {
        BitmapDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    }

    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BitmapInfo.bmiHeader);
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width; 
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;


    BitmapHandle = CreateDIBSection(
        BitmapDeviceContext,
        &BitmapInfo,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        &BitmapMemory,
        0, 0);
};

local_function void UpdateMyWindow(HDC DeviceContext, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height) {
    StretchDIBits(
        DeviceContext,
         X, Y, Width, Height,
         X, Y, Width, Height,
         &BitmapMemory,
         &BitmapInfo,
         DIB_RGB_COLORS,
         SRCCOPY
    );
}


LRESULT Wndproc(
    HWND Window,
    UINT Message,
    WPARAM unnamedParam3,
    LPARAM unnamedParam4
)
{

    switch (Message) {
        case WM_DESTROY: 
            running = false;
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            running = false;
            break;

        case WM_SIZE: {
            RECT clientRect;
            GetClientRect(Window, &clientRect);
            int Width = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
            int Height = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;
            ResizeDIBSection(Width, Height);
        }
            break;
           

        case WM_PAINT: 
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
            HDC DeviceContext = BeginPaint(Window, &Paint);

            int X = Paint.rcPaint.left;
            int Y = Paint.rcPaint.top;
            int Width = Paint.rcPaint.right - Paint.rcPaint.left;
            int Height = Paint.rcPaint.bottom - Paint.rcPaint.top;

            UpdateMyWindow(DeviceContext, X, Y, Width, Height);
            EndPaint(Window, &Paint);

        };
        break;
         

        
        default: 
            return DefWindowProcA(Window, Message, unnamedParam3, unnamedParam4);
            break;
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE Instance,
    HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
) {

    WNDCLASSEXA windowClass = {};
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    windowClass.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = Wndproc;
    windowClass.hInstance = Instance;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "Game";


    if (RegisterClassExA(&windowClass)) {
        HWND windowHandle = CreateWindowExA(
            0,
            windowClass.lpszClassName,
            "My Window",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0,
            0,
            Instance,
            0
        );
        if (windowHandle) {
            MSG Message;
            while (running) {
                BOOL messageResult = GetMessage(&Message, 0, 0, 0);
                if (messageResult > 0) {
                    TranslateMessage(&Message);
                    DispatchMessageA(&Message);
                }
                else {
                    //In here the Data saving and everything else is handled.
                    break;
                }
            }
             
        }
        else {
            MessageBoxA(0, "windowHandle failure", "Bruh", 0);
            //Add error handling;
        }
    }
    else {
        //Error Handling
        MessageBoxA(0, "RegisterClass failure", "Bruh", 0);
    }
        
};
```

I wasn't expecting it to show other window's like that. I can't really find anything about it on google either. From what I have seen, the Bitmap has no connection to other window's in any way (at least currently) so I am a bit confused on why it act's the way it does. This is the first time I'm using Stack overflow. If there is something I'm not doing right, please tell me.